# Error conectando Java con SQL

Tags: java, sql

Tengo un problema con este codigo:

**CÓDIGO**

```
package restaurante2;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
//import.java.util.*;

public class Registro extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Registro() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public class Conexion {
        public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        String servidor="127.0.0.1:8080";
        String user="system";
        String pass="2100";         
        String driver="oracle.jdb.driver.OracleDiver";
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        Connection   conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("127.0.0.1:8080,restaurante,2100");    
        return conexion;
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabelNumOrden = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabelCliente = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabelPlatillo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextNumOrden = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextFieldCliente = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextFieldPlatillo = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        Alta = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Baja = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Editar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButtonSAL = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabelNumOrden.setText("NumOrden");

        jLabelCliente.setText("Cliente");

        jLabelPlatillo.setText("Platillo");

        jTextNumOrden.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jTextNumOrdenKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextFieldCliente.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextFieldClienteActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jTextFieldCliente.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jTextFieldClienteKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        Alta.setText("Alta");
        Alta.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                AltaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Baja.setText("Baja");
        Baja.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                BajaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        Editar.setText("Editar");
        Editar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                EditarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButtonSAL.setText("X");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabelPlatillo)
                    .addComponent(jLabelCliente)
                    .addComponent(jLabelNumOrden))
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldCliente, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 158, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextNumOrden)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldPlatillo))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButtonSAL))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(58, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(Alta)
                .addGap(44, 44, 44)
                .addComponent(Baja)
                .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                .addComponent(Editar)
                .addGap(81, 81, 81))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabelNumOrden)
                                    .addComponent(jTextNumOrden, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                                .addComponent(jLabelCliente))
                            .addComponent(jTextFieldCliente, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addComponent(jButtonSAL))
                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabelPlatillo)
                    .addComponent(jTextFieldPlatillo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 72, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(Alta)
                    .addComponent(Baja)
                    .addComponent(Editar))
                .addGap(53, 53, 53))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void AltaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void BajaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void EditarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    private void jTextNumOrdenKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
     char c= evt.getKeyChar();     

     if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
        getToolkit().beep();

        evt.consume();


     }
    }                                      

    private void jTextFieldClienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                                 

    private void jTextFieldClienteKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                           
       //evento envocado
        char c=evt.getKeyChar();
        //convertimos char la tecla pulsada

        if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
            //pregunta si es digito
            getToolkit().beep();
            //alerta
            evt.consume();
            //bloquea
            Error.setText("Solo letras");

        }
    }                                          

    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {

      String jTextFieldCliente = null;
    String jTextFieldPlatillo = null;
    int jTextNumOrden = 0;

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    String sql = null;  

    try{
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("127.0.0.1:8080,restaurante,2100");
        String query = "insert into menu (numorden,cliente,platillo)values(?,?,?)";
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setInt(1, jTextNumOrden);
        pstmt.setString(2,jTextFieldCliente);
        pstmt.setString(3, jTextFieldPlatillo);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        pstmt.close();
        con.close();
      }
    }

    public static void Update(){
    String jTextFieldCliente = null;
    String jTextFieldPlatillo = null;
    int jTextNumOrden = 0;

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    String sql = null;
     try{
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("127.0.0.1:8080,restaurante , 2100");
        String query = "delete from menu where (numorden = ?,cliente = ? and platillo =?)";

        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setInt(1, jTextNumOrden);
        pstmt.setString(2,jTextFieldCliente);
        pstmt.setString(3, jTextFieldPlatillo);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        pstmt.close();
        con.close();
      }
    }
    public static void Delete(){
    String jTextFieldCliente = null;
    String jTextFieldPlatillo = null;
    int jTextNumOrden = 0;

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    String sql = null;

    try{
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("127.0.0.1:8080,restaurante , 2100");
        String query = "de into menu (numorden,cliente,platillo)values(?,?,?)";
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setInt(1, jTextNumOrden);
        pstmt.setString(2,jTextFieldCliente);
        pstmt.setString(3, jTextFieldPlatillo);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        pstmt.close();
        con.close();
      }
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton Alta;
    private javax.swing.JButton Baja;
    private javax.swing.JButton Editar;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButtonSAL;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelCliente;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelNumOrden;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelPlatillo;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldCliente;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldPlatillo;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextNumOrden;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**Arroja el siguiente error**

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 127.0.0.1:8080,restaurante,2100
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at restaurante2.Registro.main(Registro.java:204)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at restaurante2.Registro.main(Registro.java:214)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

off topic : perdi acceso a mi cuenta anterior, tenia mucha reputacion, esto lo aclaro para dejar en claro que no soy un noob que solo busca que le solucionen un problema, tambien aporte en su tiempo, este era mi usuario https://stackoverflow.com/users/209797/agelessessence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método [getConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) recibe por parámetro 3 Strings `(url,nombreusuario,contraseña)`y en su código solo le envía un solo String de forma incorrecta *(separado por coma)*. además si se usa variables para dicho acceso es mejor **hacer uso de ellas.**.

**Asumo que la base de datos tiene por nombre "restaurante" y que el servidor se ejecuta en el puerto 8080**

```
public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String url ="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:8080:restaurante";
    String user="system";
    String pass="2100";         
    String driver="oracle.jdb.driver.OracleDiver";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection   conexion=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);    
    return conexion;
}
```

Tener en cuenta que el método [getConnection(String url)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-) también acepta un solo String pero hay que construir dicho String correctamente.

```
String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:system/2100@127.0.0.1:8080:restaurante";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
```

Comment: vale! te agradezco el aporte, deja pruebo lo que me comentas, gracias! :D

Answer (score 1):

Tu `getConnection()` para **Oracle** debe ser así:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
  ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:8080:restaurante", "user", "pass");
```

Donde **orcl** es tu BD, **user** el usuario y **pass** la contraseña.

También debes asegurarte de agragar el jar de tu driver al Java Build Path de tu proyecto

Comment: Lo siento, no me percate que ya había una respuesta con el URL como debe ser

Comment: de todas maneras es buena respuesta, te agradezco ;)